# Writing out a zip file doesn't work in IE7

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, zip

I have inherited an old application that stores a zip file in a database and needs to retrieve this file. In Firefox is works fine, I can open the zip and each file inside it is fine.  When I run it in IE7 I get the following error.

> Internet Explorer cannot download ProductContentFormImage.aspx from localhost.
>
> Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later.

I am using the code below.

```
byte[] content = (byte[])Session["contentBinary"];

Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();

Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Expires = 0;
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", content.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=content.zip");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.BinaryWrite(content);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a weird little bug specific to IE.

Basically, the problem presents itself when you set your expiry to 0.

IE basically goes through the following process:

1. IE determines that the file is something to be "downloaded", which causes IE to open the File Download pop-up.
2. Once the user clicks on "Open" or "Save", IE tries to download the file, but since it's set to expire immediately, IE trips up.

Set your expiry to a small non-zero number like 1 minute and you should see the problem go away.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that setting HttpCacheability to private fixes the issue

```
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
```